# STH-Comet - cors issues in docker image

Tags: fiware, fiware-sth-comet

I'm using STH-Comet and I cannot use the APIs in my ReactJS application for CORS issues. Is there a way to enable the cors configuration via docker env var?
I could try it just set cors.enable = true (of config.js file) in the docker container. Thanks a lot.